# two navigations main navi on fixed top and sub navi stickey

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am doing a web page with **bootstrap**. Main navigation is on fixed top position. Sub navigation is below the banner. When scrolling both should be on top of the page sub navigation should stop below the main navigation with a background colour change. Anyone can help me?

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');


<style type="text/css">

.innernav{
 background-color:#FFF;
 font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
    color:#212121;
 font-size:14px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
.navbar .navbar-header,
.navbar-collapse {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.innernav .navbar-inner > .container {text-align:center; }

.inner-banner{
 height:430px;}
 
.inside{
 background:url(../images/inside_bg.png) repeat-x;
 background-position:50% 50%;}
 
.inside .navbar-nav{
 background-color:#FFF;
}
.no-horizontal-padding {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
.affix {
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #d52027;
}
```

```html
<!-- star main navbar -->
<div class="container innernav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo-inner.jpg"></a> </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">our products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">about tea</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">media</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">locater</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<!-- end main navbar -->
</div>
<section id="banner">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <!--start banner ares-->
    <div class="row"> 
     <div class="inner-banner">
         <!--**********banner area************-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end banner ares--> 
  </div>
</section>

<section id="main-content"> 
<!--start inner page navi-->
  <div class="container-fluid no-horizontal-padding">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default inside" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="400">
          <div class="container text-center">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Global presence</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Certification</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Our Facilities</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end inner page navi-->
   <div class="container-fluid">
   
    <!--******body content*****-->
   
   </div>
  </section>
```

here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/prasha/zd6yecgm/

Comment: Where's the html and css?

Comment: @Mike Tung here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/prasha/zd6yecgm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Change HTML

```
<nav id="navigation" class="" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="400">
          <div class="container text-center">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Global presence</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Certification</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Our Facilities</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
.affix {
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #d52027;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zd6yecgm/1/

Comment: Thanks, awesome. I got a small problem again the content below the sub nav now goes on top of it. Please check the fiddle now. How can I overcome it.
https://jsfiddle.net/prasha/zd6yecgm/4/

Comment: add z-index ".affix" this class

Comment: @ LaljiTadhani.Oh cool I thought z-index should only use with a CSS positioning (absolute or relative). You just made my day.

Comment: yes this class apply position fixed on bootstrap css

Comment: hi @ LaljiTadhani..just a small question again. why does my navbar-toggle dosent work here.https://jsfiddle.net/prasha/464hk5oz/

Comment: remove inline-block  ".navbar .navbar-header,
.navbar-collapse"

Comment: change some html your ID & data-target not same